# Can you continue playing after you finish the main storyline?

Tags: fable-3

I have a dozen side quests pending in my quest list, but I'm tempted to complete the main story first.

Is it possible to keep playing the game even after you're done with the story?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Yes.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30476/can-you-continue-playing-after-you-finish-the-main-storyline/30478#30478)

Comment: [YES](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-hdxds3V-0&t=55s)

Comment: Creative answer +1 XD